# Subclass Polymer element filling base class insertion points

Tags: javascript, html, polymer-2.x

I have a set of Polymer components which are subclasses of another component. I want to populate the template of the superclass based on the template of the subclass. (See [here](https://blog.quickui.org/2013/06/11/puzzle-define-html-custom-element-subclasses-that-can-fill-in-base-class-insertion-points/) for someone else looking for a solution to a similar problem, unfortunately with no solution.) The usage looks something like this:

```html
<!-- control.html -->
<media-tabs tabs-title="Alternative input">
  <template>
    <media-blackout></media-blackout>
    <media-slates></media-slates>
    <media-playlists></media-playlists>
    <media-queue></media-queue>
  </template>
</media-tabs>
```

```html
<!-- media-tabs.html -->
<paper-card heading="[[tabsTitle]]" class="fill-h fill-v">
  <div class="card-content">
    <paper-tabs id="tabs" selected="{{selectedIndex}}" selectable>
    </paper-tabs>
    <iron-pages id="content" selected="{{selectedIndex}}">
    </iron-pages>
  </div>
</paper-card>
```

```js
// media-tabs.js
ready() {
  super.ready();
  this.selectedIndex = 0;
  const template = this.querySelector('template');
  const instance = this._stampTemplate(template);
  const tabs = Array.from(instance.children);
  tabs.forEach((elm) => {
    const content = elm.constructor.template.content;
    this.$.tabs.appendChild(content.querySelector('#title'));
    this.$.content.appendChild(content.querySelector('#content'));
  });
}
```

```html
<!-- media-tab.html -->
<paper-tab id="title"></paper-tab>
<div id="content"></div>
```

```html
<!-- media-blackout.html -->
<span id="title">Blackout</span>
<div id="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
<!-- repeat above for media-playlists, media-queue, and media-slates -->
```

```js
// media-blackout.js -- is a subclass of media-tab
static get template() {
  if (!superTemplate) {
    const thisTemplate = Polymer.DomModule.import(this.is, 'template');
    superTemplate = MediaTab.template.cloneNode(true);
    const title = thisTemplate.content.querySelector('#title').textContent;
    const content = thisTemplate.content.querySelector('#content');
    const children = Array.from(content.children);

    superTemplate.content.querySelector('#title').innerHTML = title;
    children.forEach((child) => {
      superTemplate.content.querySelector('#content').appendChild(child);
    });
  }
  return superTemplate;
}
// repeat above for media-playlists, media-queue, and media-slates
```

This setup works. However, the `template()` getter is **identical** in the media-tab subclasses, and I want to find a way to move that logic into the superclass, without the code in the superclass needing to know about the subclass implementation details.

I have attempted to create getters for the two fields the superclass would need to pull from (eg, `const title = this.templateTitleElement.textContent;`), however my implementations either poke the element's `template` property in some way (resulting a stack overflow), or else try to access elements before they're available (eg, `return this.$.title;`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous solution had issues with bubbling events from within the tab content, so I was forced to come up with another solution:

```html
<!-- control.html -->
<media-tabs tabs-title="Alternative input" on-play-slate="handlePlayTapped">
  <media-blackout></media-blackout>
  <media-slates></media-slates>
  <media-playlists></media-playlists>
  <media-queue></media-queue>
</media-tabs>
```

You can see I've removed the template from the `media-tabs` declaration.

```html
<!-- media-tabs.html -->
<paper-card heading="[[tabsTitle]]">
  <div class="card-content">
    <paper-tabs id="tabs" selected="{{selectedIndex}}" selectable></paper-tabs>
    <iron-pages id="content" selected="[[selectedIndex]]">
      <slot></slot>
    </iron-pages>
  </div>
</paper-card>
```

You can see that I've added the `<slot>` insertion point to the iron-pages.

```js
// media-tabs.js
ready() {
  super.ready();
  const children = Array.from(this.children);
  children.forEach((child) => {
    const template = Object.getPrototypeOf(child.constructor).template;
    const instance = this._stampTemplate(template);
    instance.$.title.innerHTML = child.tabTitle;
    this.$.tabs.appendChild(instance.$.title);
  });
}
```

Now I only append children to the `paper-tabs` element, rather than both `paper-tabs` and `iron-pages`. `Object.getPrototypeOf(child.constructor)` returns the constructor of `child`'s superclass; this means I'm not simply assuming the child's superclass is MediaTab, although this can be improved as I *am* assuming the child's superclass has an element with `id="title"` and a property `tabTitle`.

```html
<!-- media-tab.html -->
<paper-tab id="title"></paper-tab>
```

```js
// media-tab.js
static get properties() {
  return {
    tabTitle: String,
  };
}
```

The `media-tab` template doesn't contain a content div any more, and the superclass defines the `tabTitle` property referenced in `media-tabs.js`.

```html
<!-- media-blackout.html -->
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<!-- repeat above for media-playlists, media-queue, and media-slates -->
```

The `media-tab` subclasses no longer store their tab title in HTML, they only have content.

```js
// media-blackout.js
class MediaBlackout extends MediaTab {
  // ...

  static get properties() {
    return {
      tabTitle: {
        type: String,
        value: 'Blackout',
        readOnly: true,
      },
    };
  }
}
// repeat above for media-playlists, media-queue, and media-slates
```

Instead of having the subclass's title in a `span`, it's defined as a property of the class.

This solution doesn't use a mixin, and events being fired from within the `MediaTab` elements can bubble up to the top of the app.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to come up with a solution using mixins; it's not quite the inheritance of classical OOP, but it functions without replicating the same function four times.

```js
// title-content-mixin.js
const titleContentMixin = (function() {
  const titleContentMixin = (superClass, options = {}) => {
    const titleQuery = options.titleQuery || '#title';
    const contentQuery = options.contentQuery || '#content';
    const superTitleQuery = options.superTitleQuery || titleQuery;
    const superContentQuery = options.superContentQuery || contentQuery;

    return class TitleContentMixin extends superClass {
      static get template() {
        if (this.is === superClass.is || superClass.is.length === 0) return;

        const thisTemplate = Polymer.DomModule.import(this.is, 'template')
            .cloneNode(true);
        const superTemplate = superClass.template.cloneNode(true);
        const title = thisTemplate.content.querySelector(titleQuery).textContent;
        const content = thisTemplate.content.querySelector(contentQuery);
        const children = Array.from(content.children);

        superTemplate.content.querySelector(superTitleQuery).innerHTML = title;
        children.forEach((child) => {
          superTemplate.content.querySelector(superContentQuery)
              .appendChild(child);
        });
        return superTemplate;
      }
    };
  };

  return Polymer.dedupingMixin(titleContentMixin);
})();
```

```js
// media-blackout.js
class MediaBlackout extends titleContentMixin(MediaTab) {
  // ...
}
// repeat above for media-playlists, media-queue, and media-slates
```